# ExecutorService execute method in java

Tags: java, multithreading

According to `Runnable execute` method in `Executor`, corresponding JAVA doc mentions that it:

> Executes the given command at some time in the future.  The command
>    may execute in a new thread, in a pooled thread, or in the calling
>    thread, at the discretion of the {@code Executor} implementation.

My doubt is, for example if we create executor service as

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
```

and create a `Runnable` task and run it by the above `execute` method as:

```
Runnable testRunnableTask = () ->  {
      Runnable testRunnableTask = () ->  {
          System.out.println("my tested function");
      } 
 };
executor.execute(testRunnableTask);
```

Then this `testRunnableTask` should be executed by one of the threads that we have initialized through our fixed thread pool. But as per JAVA doc it can be executed by new thread or thread pool or calling thread.

If my understanding is correct of JAVA doc, then my doubt is why `execute` method doesn't always use one of the threads from the pool like other methods of `ExecutorService` like `submit`.

Comment: That's just the specification for the `execute` method of executors. I believe your answer lies more with `newFixedThreadPool(nThread)`, which produces the implementation "at whose discretion" the executing thread is selected. I'd start with the docs of that factory, then look at how its related implementation schedules tasks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The command may execute in a new thread, in a pooled thread, or in the calling thread, at the **discretion of the {@code Executor} implementation**.

So, basically this means that how a `Runnable` or `Callable` task works depends on the `Executor` overall implementation, not the specific method execution. `Executor` is just an abstraction which provides an API to execute some lambda or task in a way that is up to the implementation.

So in your particular case `executor.execute(testRunnableTask);` because you are using `newFixedThreadPool` then `testRunnableTask` will be executed in one of 5 pre-initialized threads. If you would use `Executors.newCachedThreadPool()`, the task might be executed either in new or cached thread. And so on.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Could add here as an example that there are policies available to deal with being flooded with work, for instance to push back by running tasks in the calling thread, which the executor can be configured to use. and that the verbiage in the api doc is left vague to allow for this kind of thing.

Comment: @NathanHughes thank you so much for your comment, I'm afraid I'm not really following you. Do you the case of submitting task to ForkJoin pool from the thread which is a part of the pool?

Comment: i meant like rejection policies: ."for pools with a bounded work queue, task rejections occur when the queue is full and no more workers can be added. You can configure a handler to run when such a rejection occurs. These handlers are called "Policies". .. You can choose to use another Policy such as the DiscardPolicy, which simply discards the task silently; the CallerRunsPolicy, which executes the task on the calling thread instead of one of the worker threads' https://dzone.com/articles/a-deep-dive-into-the-java-executor-service

Comment: @NathanHughes Oh wow, I did not know that. I think it would be more fair if you will post an another answer, so community can pay you for this knowledge with reputation. I'll definitely up-vote it

Answer (score 1):

`submit` will submit a task for execution by `execute`. In other words, `submit` internally calls `execute` to execute the task.

How `execute` will execute the task depends on the configuration or constructor you use for `ThreadPoolExecutor`

```
public ThreadPoolExecutor(int corePoolSize,
                          int maximumPoolSize,
                          long keepAliveTime,
                          TimeUnit unit,
                          BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue,
                          ThreadFactory threadFactory,
                          RejectedExecutionHandler handler)
```

1. Idle threads will die if the total number of threads is more than `corePoolSize`
2. If the number of tasks submitted are more than `corePoolSize`, new threads will be created until `maximumPoolSize` is reached
3. `handler` implementation gives a saturation policy that determines what wil happen when all the threads are executing tasks and the **bounded** blocking queue is also full. If the handler implementation passed is `ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy`, the caller thread will execute the task
4. `newFixedThreadPool` is a specialized instance of `ThreadPoolExecutor` as given below. The `corePoolSize` and `maximumPoolSize` are same. The saturation policy is not provided - hence the default policy `ThreadPoolExecutor.AbortPolicy` is used.

```
return new ThreadPoolExecutor(nThreads, nThreads,
                                      0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
                                      new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());
```